# 1 day difference datefield in extjs

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, extjs, javascript

I have a datefield in extjs 2.2 and the problem is that every time I'm in a month to select a date, select my date prior to this for example are now in September, if I select the 13th, me on the 12th leaves selected and always happens in the month that I am, if I see the days of the past month does not give me error.

I do not have stalled this several weeks ago, hopefully they can help me.

CODE:

```
var form = new Ext.FormPanel({
            items: [{
                region: 'center',   
                xtype: 'panel',   
                layout: 'anchor',  
                border: false, 
                layoutConfig: {   
                    titleCollapse: false,   
                    animate: false,   
                    activeOnTop: false  
                },   
                items: [{   
                    height: 80,
                    frame : false,
                    collapsible: false, 
                    border: false,
                    title: false,
                    bodyStyle: 'padding:5px',
                    items: [{  
                        layout: 'column',  
                        border: false,
                        items:[{  
                            columnWidth: .1,  
                            layout: 'form',
                            labelSeparator: ' ' ,
                            labelWidth: 10,
                            labelAlign: 'top', 
                            border: false,
                            items: [{
                                        xtype: 'datefield',   
                                        id: 'date_init',   
                                        name: 'date_init',   
                                        fieldLabel: 'Date',
                                        readOnly: false,
                                        disabled: false,
                                        format: 'd/m/Y',
                                        value: new Date
                                    }]
                            },{ 
                            columnWidth: .1,  
                            layout: 'form', 
                            labelAlign: 'top', 
                            labelSeparator: ' ' ,
                            labelWidth: 10, 
                            border: false,
                            items: [{
                                    xtype: 'datefield',   
                                    id: 'date_end',   
                                    name: 'date_end',   
                                    fieldLabel: 'End',
                                    readOnly: false,
                                    disabled: false,
                                    format: 'd/m/Y',
                                    value: new Date
                                }]
                            },{ 
                            columnWidth: .17,  
                            layout: 'form', 
                            labelAlign: 'top', 
                            labelSeparator: ' ' ,
                            labelWidth: 10, 
                            border: false,
                            items: [{
                                    xtype: 'combo',
                                    store: storeLocal,
                                    valueField: 'idMarket',
                                    displayField:'nameMarket',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Market',
                                    mode: 'local',
                                    value:'-- ALL --',
                                    triggerAction: 'all',
                                    width: 190,
                                    selectOnFocus:true,
                                    hiddenName: 'idMarket',
                                    id : 'id_market_id'//,
                                    //allowBlank: false
                                }]
                            },{
                            columnWidth: .3,
                            layout: 'form',
                            border: false,
                            labelWidth: 70,
                            items:[{
                                xtype: 'button',
                                text: 'Search',
                                arrowAlign: 'right',
                                icon: '../img/icons/find.png',
                                cls: 'x-btn-text-icon',
                                ctCls: 'x-btn-style',
                                width: 80,
                                handler: function(){    
                                        if(formulario.form.isValid()) {
                                           groupStore.load();
                                        }
                                    }         
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]  
                }]
        });
```

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by changing the version of ext, from 2.2 to 3.4